# PhantomJS - Handling Network Error

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

When I run my PhantomJS script in debug mode, I see sometimes this error : [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: 5 ( "Operation canceled" ).

When I run my script 1000 times, I've this error 1 or 2 times. I want to catch it without running my script in debug mode but I don't know how !

I try several error handlers :

```
phantom.onError = function(msg, trace) {
  console.log("PhantomJS onError\n");
};

page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
  console.log("PhantomJS onError\n");
};

page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
  console.log("PhantomJS onResourceError\n");
};

page.onResourceTimeout = function(req) {
  console.error('PhantomJS onResourceTimeout\n');
};

page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
  if (status != 'success') {
    console.error('PhantomJS onLoadFinished Error\n');
  }
};
```

Do you have an idea for me ? How can I catch this error ? I use PhantomJS 1.9.7 x64 on Unix.

Thanks,

Comment: Now you have all events that might be able to show this error. You need to log the arguments that are passed into the handlers to see which one is the right one. My money is either on `page.onError` or `page.onResourceError`. Also, what do you mean by *catching*? You will probably have to stop the further execution based on this from the event handler itself and restart again.

Comment: Hello, yes I want to "catch" the error to launch a new execution. My problem is that no handler is call when I see the error in debug !

Answer (score 0):

This question may be old but I had the same trouble today and found a workaround:

```
var numberOfRequests = 0;
page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
    if (numberOfRequests === 0) {
        // if status of first resource is NULL there was a network error
        if (response.status === null) {
            console.log('[ERROR] Loading page failed: Network error');
            phantom.exit();
        }
    }

    numberOfRequests++;
};
```

Tested with phantomJS 2.1. Hope this may help anybody else.